# Mage Report - Unprotected Development Files

Tags: magento-enterprise, htaccess

I've been reviewing the unprotected development files issue on Mage Report and have noticed that we already have a .htaccess file in with the correct recommendations however the report is still showing as unprotected.

Is there anything else we need to do with this example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I work with the community edition therefore I'm not sure if the problem can be fixed the same way... I could solve that problem by deleting the dev-folder and copy the dev-folder from the newest magento version. I guess my problem was caused by a .htaccess file in dev/tests/functional/ from an older magento version which isn't available in the newest magento version (1.9.3.1). (I did only override the existing files and the old files in the dev folder remained.)